# H264 Decoding in WP8 using DirectX

Tags: video, directx, windows-phone-8, h.264

I know that in Windows Phone 8 I can using DirectX 11 and
I need manually to decode h264 frames.

So how I can do it using DirectX ?

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to do "decode H264" isn't a goal by itself AFAIK.

To play Video in WP8 D3D you can use the new [Media Foundation APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681688%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). See code example on MSDN @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207074(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I have custom container for H264 frames. And I can't set Url for my source because MediaEngine does not know how process it. In normal Media Foundation I can use ByteStreamHandler and SourceReader which I can implement, but WP8 does not have these APIs? 

So how I can do it? 

In little words: I have a srteam which contains audio and video frames, I want to parse him and translate frames to texture which I can display for user.

Comment: You'll need to use a XAML MediaElement and create a custom MediaStreamSource. MediaStreamSource will get the raw bytes, unpack the H264 frames and feed them to the MediaElement. There's a sample for a custom MediaStreamSource for unpacking MP3 frames over at @ https://github.com/loarabia/ManagedMediaHelpers

Comment: Justin, I know about this solution. And for WP7 I already implemented that. But this solution is... not good, because native MediaElement is bad (for example I can't clear buffers if I need for MediaElement and have issues with it)

Comment: In this time I using "workaround" - set the position for MediaElement which clears buffers and begins process frames which I need, but mediaElement stopping to 300 - 1000 milliseconds in this cases - and this is very very bad.